# FREAK on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

Folks,

I use Raspbian's native SFTP (not to be confused with FTPS) as well as SSH shell over the internet to access my files remotely. Just wondering if FREAK has any bearing on SFTP/SSH? If Raspbian is affected then I'd like to know how to address the situation.

**Additional Info**: I do not use any service other than SFTP. I do not use the bundled browser or any other UI-based software.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No risk for you.

According to https://freakattack.com/

> The FREAK attack is possible when a vulnerable browser connects to a
>   susceptible web server—a server that accepts “export-grade”
>   encryption.

Software at risk are web browsers

You can check whether your browser is vulnerable using the [FREAK Client Test Tool](https://freakattack.com/clienttest.html).